# Execute Code From Memory on Windows 10 c++ x64?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, executable

I'm trying to figure out how to execute arbitrary code on Windows 10. I feel like this code should work, but it's giving me an Access violation writing location error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <Windows.h>

// x64 assembly
#define ret (uint8_t)(0xc3)
#define nop (uint8_t)(0x90)

int main() {
    std::vector<uint8_t> raw_code = {
        nop, ret
    };

    LPVOID exec = VirtualAlloc(NULL, raw_code.size(), MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    memcpy(exec, raw_code.data(), raw_code.size());

    DWORD old_protect;
    VirtualProtect(exec, raw_code.size(), PAGE_EXECUTE, &old_protect); // Line where error occurs

    ((void(*)())exec)();

    VirtualProtect(exec, raw_code.size(), old_protect, &old_protect);
    VirtualFree(exec, raw_code.size(), MEM_RELEASE);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to COMMIT the allocated memory before you can write the `raw_code` data into it. This code is only RESERVE'ing the memory

Comment: @RemyLebeau Wow. Such a simple mistake. It seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for one thing `MEM_RESERVE` means the memory isn't allocated, so trying to dereference the pointer will cause an access violation (as you saw for yourself). Don't be cute and just allocate your memory as normal, using `MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE`.

You also aren't setting your memory to be executable, you need to use `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` instead. Otherwise, with DEP enabled, your code will crash with access violation.

Comment: "*You also aren't setting your memory to be executable*" - yes, it is.  The memory is being set to `PAGE_EXECUTE` *after* copying the bytecode into it. That will suffice, you don't need or want `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` since you don't want outside code being able to alter your bytecode while it is executing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: If this is for testing shellcode, such code is sometimes written to be self-modifying (e.g. to insert zeros into string data), so for that you actually *would* just want to allocate memory with RWX permissiong.  Code-injection buffer overflow exploits are usually only possible in pages that are already RWX, although I guess it's plausible you could inject the code and then (maybe via a ROP attack) get VirtualProtect called on it before returning to the code itself, defeating W^X security.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the error occurs on the following line (at least, it does when I run your code):

```cpp
    memcpy(exec, raw_code.data(), raw_code.size());
```

This is because your call to `VirtualAlloc` only *reserves* memory, but does not actually *commit* it. [From the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc):

> MEM_RESERVE (0x00002000)
>  Reserves a range of the process's
> virtual address space without allocating any actual physical storage
> in memory or in the paging file on disk.

To commit the memory (i.e., make it *usable*), you need to add the `MEM_COMMIT` flag:

```cpp
    LPVOID exec = VirtualAlloc(nullptr, raw_code.size(), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

With this flag added, you code runs on my Windows 10 (built with clang-cl/VS-2019) without error.